# Avoiding snap packages in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, snap

Ubuntu (Ubuntu 20.04 LTS) recently have gotten notorious with their snap packages (such as Chromium). They are a pain to load. This is what I am doing to keep them at bay. Anyone has any better ideas?

```
sudo rm -rf /var/cache/snapd/
sudo apt autoremove --purge snapd gnome-software-plugin-snap
rm -fr ~/snap

# (OPTIONAL) Following command will make sure snapd does not get installed again as a dependency
# Downside is that you will get an error if you try to install certain packages 
# those come only as snaps
sudo apt-mark hold snapd
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found some info in https://www.kevin-custer.com/blog/disabling-snaps-in-ubuntu-20-04/ . Consolidating the info from that post and my experimentation, here is what needs to be done:

```
sudo apt purge snapd
rm -vrf ~/snap

# following may not be required as apt purge already removes them
sudo rm -vrf /snap /var/snap /var/lib/snapd /var/cache/snapd /usr/lib/snapd

# (OPTIONAL STEP) 
# Trying to install some package like chromium-browser will bring back snapd
# make sure snapd is not installed as a dependency anymore
# downside is that some package installation might fail because of dependecy on snapd
sudo apt-mark hold snapd
```